# serious disk performance problems, please help,

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance, ramdisk

I have a Dell inspiron 7720

processor intelr core tm i7 3630qm 
8 gm ram

the problem is that me disk is always between 49% - 50%, then I noticed my disk had some "partitions" named as disk 0c: and disk 1

disk 0 is always at 100%
and disk 1 at 0%

my pc has an slot to attach another disk but I don't have another one, so I don't know whats going on. I'll attach some pics.

[image: http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/150217061147104416.png]
[image: http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/150217061147617728.png]

I'd be very appreciate if you're able to help me

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the HDD activity: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60

Comment: You have a "Disk space Cleanup..." running. If you stop that service/application does it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand what you are asking, but it seems to me like your disk has more then 1 partition, and for whatever reason there is a lot of access on the primary partition - That level of utilisation would be somewhat alarming to me as well.  Its also possible that the second disk is something else - like USB key.

I wonder if the problem is an application which is eating up your memory and there is a swap file on the drive which is being very heavily used.